# dangerdeep: preprocessor error: #version must appear on the first line

Tags: 14.04, games

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system and I tried to install the game `dangerdeep`, version 0.3.0. Upon starting the game, I can select a mission, but then the game crashes with the following output on the Linux console:

```
console log: $ffffffDanger $c0c0c0from the $ffffffDeep
console log: $ffff00copyright and written 2003 by $ff0000Thorsten Jordan
console log: $ff8000version 0.3.0
console log: $80ff80*** welcome ***
console log: New thread [0xf47a1b40]
console log: Loading...
console log: Textures with non-power-two sizes are supported and used.
console log: fonts loaded (115ms)
console log: textures loaded (74ms)
console log: Music list loaded (141ms)
console log: Loading...
console log: Using OpenGL GLSL shaders...
console log: shader compiled successfully, log:
console log:  
console log: shader compiled successfully, log:
console log:  
console log: compiling failed, log:
console log: 0:3(1): preprocessor error: #version must appear on the first line

console log: End thread [0xf47a1b40]
Caught exception: compiling of shader failed : /usr/share/games/dangerdeep/shaders/modelrender.vshader
Stack trace: (5 frames)
0x8070202 in  at ??:?
0x806d431 in  at ??:0
0x806d4f1 in  at ??:0
0xf7070af3 in __libc_start_main at ??:0
0x804e6a1 in  at ??:0
```

Can this be fixed?

Comment: As side note, 14.04 is really old. LTS versions even when released have outdated software *(for a reason, but the target audience would rather be servers and such rather than users)*, and your system is like double outdated. Consider upgrading it at least to a newer LTS. Btw, it might be well possible that your game has the bug fixed in a newer release.

Comment: 14.04 is still a supported release (although it is kinda old).

Comment: @OrganicMarble that's not the point. Just look [graphics drivers version for 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mesa&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) — 10.1. That makes me smile. Last bugfix release *(not even features)* for 10.1 was June 24, 2014, and last bugfix release for whole 10 series *(the 10.6, to be specific)* at October 3, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

It means the game has a bug that `#version` directive in GLSL shader appears not on the first line. Imagine that half the shader parsed as one GLSL version, and then the other half as another — it would make no sense! So the compiler just bails out with the error.

In general there's `.drirc` file for dealing with alike misbehaving apps, however looking at `xdriinfo options r600 | grep version` I see nothing to deal with the specific problem *(note though that I didn't look really carefully, so I could miss it)*.

I see no easy way to deal with the problem. You can α) report a bug to the game developers, β) since the game is FOSS, try fixing the problem yourself *(Mesa has a bunch of options to debug, e.g. you [can dump GLSL](https://www.mesa3d.org/shading.html#envvars) to figure out which shader has the problem)* γ) edit the userspace driver to ignore the problem, and compile/install it.